# Bulk loading (BULK Insert) with multiple amounts of whitespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, bulkinsert, openrowset

I'm trying to import a TXT file using the BULK INSERT function using SQL Server.
The data in the text file appears as such:

```
XDB          XDB_XTABNMSP        FLAGS        NUMBER       6
XDB          XDB_INDEX_DDL_CACHE       ROOT_TABLE_NAME       VARCHAR2       1
XDB          XDB_INDEX_DDL_CACHE       ROOT_TABLE_OWNER       VARCHAR2       2
```

All the values are separated by a "variable" amount of whitespaces. It could be separated by 5 spaces, sometimes 8 spaces, etc.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
BULK INSERT MyTableName
FROM 'D:\MyTXTFileName.txt'
WITH (

  FIELDTERMINATOR = ' '
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
, FIRSTROW=2
)
```

How can I set the column delimiter (FIELDTERMINATOR) so that it separates the values on ANY amount of whitespace?

Expected Result:

```
XDB XDB_XTABNMSP        FLAGS               NUMBER     6
XDB XDB_INDEX_DDL_CACHE ROOT_TABLE_NAME     VARCHAR2   1
XDB XDB_INDEX_DDL_CACHE ROOT_TABLE_OWNER    VARCHAR2   2
```

Comment: bcp.exe/BULK INSERT cannot handle variable files like this. You'd have to either (1) pre-process it with an external tool to transform it to CSV, XML or some other format, then read that in via bcp.exe/BULK INSERT, or (2) read it in as a SINGLE_CLOB or SINGLE_NCLOB and process the contents inside SQL with string functions. Option 1 would be better, especially if this will be a regular import. SQL Server isn't exactly fantastic at parsing and manipulating string data.

Comment: what is that number at the end of each row (6, 1, 2)?

Comment: @sacse - Oops, that's an additional column, I forgot to include in the expected result!